# como puedo redireccionar a otro componente en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo un Switch y cuando recibo la respuesta de Dalefon quiero que me mande en automatico a la hoja de Dalefon ¿alguien puede apoyarme ?

```
switch (respuesta) {
          case "Phone":
            return <HomePhone />;
          case "Dalefon":
            return <HomeDalefon />;
          default:
            dayName = "No existe!!";
        }
```

Comment: Para hacer una navegacion debes agregar la dependencia react router, aqui tienes info https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start. Si solo quieres renderizar un componente u otro debes crear una variable de estado y en el return usar un condicional para que dependiendo de dicha variable se renderice el componente

Comment: estaria bueno que al menos digas que version de react y react-router-dom tenes, pero deberias poder importar ``import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom"`` y luego en vez de ``return <HomeDalefon />;`` llamas a ``return <Redirect to='/dalefon' />`` o el nombre de la ruta. Para ello deberias crear el enrutado, y pasarle a la ruta ``/dalefon`` el componente ``Dalefon`` como si fuera una vista.

Answer (score 0):

Si estas utilizando react-router-dom puedes utilizar el hook useNavigate. Comentame si te sirve. saludos

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
const navigate = useNavigate();

....

   switch (respuesta) {
      case "Phone":
        navigate('/HomePhone')
      case "Dalefon":
        navigate('/Dalefon')
      default:
        dayName = "No existe!!";
    }
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).